# Can't insert plots in bookdown

Tags: r, latex, pandoc, bookdown, blogdown

I'm using bookdown to generate notes for an R.  A minimal bookdown example that exhibits the error:

https://github.com/DavisBrian/bookdown_error

Everything worked great until I tried to add a plot (dataviz.Rmd).  When building the book I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `dataviz_files/figure-latex/plotxyx-1' not found.

Error: Failed to compile rclassnotes.tex. See rclassnotes.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)) :
  Failed to find a package that contains dataviz_files/figure-latex/plotxyx-1
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I've run this under:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.4  backports_1.1.2 bookdown_0.7    magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.4    
 [8] yaml_2.1.18     Rcpp_0.12.16    stringi_1.1.7   rmarkdown_1.9   knitr_1.20      xfun_0.1        stringr_1.3.0  
[15] digest_0.6.15   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Edit:

It seems very similar to:
https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/issues/3
and
https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/342

Note I have this issue with both Windows and Mac OSX.  I don't think it's a simple software installation error of one of the components.

The files seem to be created in _bookdown_files/dataviz_files/figure-latex/ and temporarily in _dataviz_files/figure-latex/

Comment: Were those files created?

Comment: Yes but they seem to get delete / cleaned up.  I can see them there until the error occurs.  Side note if I use the RStudio knit button everything works fine.  But the Build Book errors out

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at. Can you try to build a minimal example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @RalfStubner Updated the link at the top to a minimal bookdown example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that you set the graphical device to `svg` in `_common.R`: https://github.com/DavisBrian/bookdown_error/blob/9f4078a/_common.R#L13

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  comment = "#>",
  collapse = TRUE,
  cache = FALSE,
  out.width = "70%",
  fig.align = 'center',
  fig.width = 6,
  fig.asp = 0.618,  # 1 / phi
  fig.show = "hold",
  dev = "svg"
)
```

LaTeX does not support SVG images natively (at least for now). You have to either use special LaTeX packages, or use an image format that LaTeX can recognize, such as `pdf` or `png`.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you for the assistance and the wonderful packages.

Comment: Thank you for [providing the reproducible example](https://yihui.name/en/2017/09/the-minimal-reprex-paradox/) in the first place :)